# Can't get the data after calling a function in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First of all I've created a class named `Roommate.Js` in which i've made a function trying to fetch data from an url this way (a random user data filtred by an id).

```
roommateDetail() {
  fetch(roommateDetail(this.props.id))
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error("Failed connection to the API")
      }

      return response
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        roommate: response
      })
    }, () => {
      this.setState({
        requestFailed: true
      })
    })
  }
```

And in other class named Roomates (plural) that show a list on random I've made this code in the render method: an `<a>` element that containt a call to the `roommateDetail` present in `Roommate` class

```
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <ul>
            {this.state.roommates.map(function(item) {
              return <a key={item.id} onClick={Roommate.roommateDetail}><li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li></a>
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Finally, in the main app render function, I'm hopping to display the result of the method call.

```
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <div className="App-center-side">
            <div className="App-center-side-content">
              <Roommate></Roommate>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

When i click an `<a>` elements, i have no return. Maybe i've made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: You're calling a function with the same name, I assume the inner ```roommateDetail``` function is defined elsewhere and the outer is an instance method for the React Component. Try calling ```preventDefault``` on the event object passed by the onClick event.

Comment: How can I make it please?

Comment: To pass in the event object just reference it in your function signature like so: ```rommateDetail(e) { e.preventDefault(); ...rest_of_function...```

Comment: this doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Oh so it looks like you're calling ```Roommate.roommateDetail``` but you should be calling ```this.roommateDetail```, and also make sure to bind ```this``` to the roommateDetail function in your class constructor

Comment: I have this type of error : Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'roommateDetail' of undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146375/discussion-between-michael-lyons-and-kubiroazhon).

Comment: A few questions: What is `this` in roommateDetail method? is roommateDetail in Roommate.Js a static function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change it like this

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
        {this.state.roommates.map(function(item) {
            return <a key={item.id} onClick={(e) => this.roommateDetail(item.id)}><li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li></a>
        })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
// add following method into your class
roommateDetail(id) {
    fetch(roommateDetail(id))
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw Error("Failed connection to the API")
        }

        return response
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          roommate: response
        })
      }, () => {
        this.setState({
          requestFailed: true
        })
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Roomate.js

```js
    class Roommate {

roommateDetail() {
fetch(roommateDetail(this.props.id))
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error("Failed connection to the API")
    }

    return response
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({
      roommate: response
    })
  }, () => {
    this.setState({
      requestFailed: true
    })
  })
}
render(){
    return (<Roommates roommateDetail={this.roommateDetail.bind(this)}/>)
   }
}
```

Roommates.js

```js
class Roommates {
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <ul>
                {this.state.roommates.map(function(item) {
                    return <a key={item.id} onClick=
                    {()=>this.props.roommateDetail}>
                    <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li></a>
                })}
            </ul>
       </div>
     )
  }
 }
```

hope this might help :)